# How to remove first screen

Tags: android

When my application is loaded, this monstrous screen appears before activity screen. How can I remove or style It?

[image: ScreenShot]

Theres is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="APP_NAME"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.drugs.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity. I have only added some code for custom title

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Without custom title this loading screen looks like

[image]

Comment: add images rather than link

Comment: looks like you loads a main activity that then loads his activity check your manifest as Photon says

Comment: yes so that i asked for the manifest the activity must not be the launcher activity

Comment: activity code also needed nothing found in manifest

Comment: have you checked in your physical device

Comment: You have given the main activity as this screen .If you want any other screen to be seen as the starting screen,make that activity as the  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: main activity code added

Comment: As you have mentioned in the comments that you have only one activity,I would like to know what you have meant by "monstrous screen appears before activity screen"??Which screen is monstrous and which screen is your activity screen?

Comment: run on physical device rather than emulator i think may be due to slow processing it taking time to load activity try On physical device

Comment: Screen on screenshot is a monstrous screen, it looks like an application loading screen. My activity screen appears after this loading screen.

Comment: I have removed custom title request from MainActivity, but this screen still exists. Same effect on physical device

Comment: The Screen that appears before the MainActivity is just because of very slow emulator on faster device the time span will be very little, This screen nothing but the MainActivity with no content. There is nothing special with this screen. Usually in debug mode it takes time to execute so it appears but not while executing without debug

Answer (score 0):

The Screen that appears before the MainActivity is just because of very slow emulator on faster device the time span will be very little, This screen nothing but the MainActivity with no content.

To set an Activity as launcher activity you need to set using these `intent-filter`

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

#### An activity which looks like following will be launcher activity

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_settings" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: what you are doing in MainActivity